# How to get Image Url from local Json file in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to be able to display images from a local folder by getting the URL from JSON file. So far I've tried :

src={require(blog.imUrl)}
src={blog.imgUrl}
src={require(`${blog.imgUrl}`)}

Errors i am getting when I use require :

Error: Cannot find module '../../images/safe-image.jpeg'

````
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Col, Row, Container, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';
import blogArticles from './blog.json';
import './BlogCard.css';

export default function BlogCard() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push('/`${blog.id}`');
  }

  return blogArticles.map((blog) => {
    return (
      <Container key={blog.id} className="blogContainer">
        <Row>
          <Col xs={6} md={6} lg={8}>
            <h3 className="blogTitle">{blog.title}</h3>
            <span className="blogBody">{blog.body.substring(0, 250)}...</span>
            <button onClick={handleClick} className="readMoreButton">
              Read More
            </button>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={4} md={4} lg={3} className="imageContainer">
            <Image src={require(blog.imgUrl)} roundedCircle />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  });
}```


Here is my JSON File structure :

{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "abc",
    "body": "abcdefg",
    "author": "as",
    "imgUrl": "../../images/leon-biss.jpg"
}
````

Comment: can you see if any errors in network tab Developers Console? like file not found something?

Comment: I am getting 304. it shows as if it's getting the image but there is no preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this for importing and showing an image which is on `src` folder (next to javascript files):

```
import img from "./img1.png";
const imgComponent = () => <img src={img} />
```

But since you want to load images from `json` file dynamically, you should put your images inside a folder like `images` in `public` folder (`public/images/img1.png`), then you can render it with:

```
<img src="/images/img1.png" />
```

- Note1: note that currently your `json` file contains the pathes relative to script file, but you should change it to the path of image in `public folder` instead. (if you can't change the `json` file, you can map that url with code also.)
- Note2: i assumed that you are using `creat-react-app` which it has `public` folder by default. if you don't have it, search for `how to serve static files in react`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried it and I got this error :

Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../public/images/safe_image.jpeg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: @Eliftch `..` means the parent folder to script.   `../../../public/images/safe_image.jpeg` means go 3 level up (parent -> parent -> parent), then access the public folder. the purpose of public folder is to serve assets to be accessible publicly. so you should change it to: `/images/safe_image.jpeg` because everything in public folder is accessible from the root url. also you shouldn't `require` or `import` it. you should use it like : `<img src="/images/safe_image.jpeg" />` .

Comment: @Eliftch here is an example: https://github.com/ya3ya6/ReactPlay1/blob/stack/src/stackoverflow_play/q1_images.js it shows this image in public folder: https://github.com/ya3ya6/ReactPlay1/blob/stack/public/logo192.png.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue because I had created an image folder inside the src folder and as a result i was unable to display the image. All I had to do to fix this was to:

- move the image folder inside the public folder at the project root folder.
- from the json file, call the image like "/images/productImages/product1.jpeg" .

Hope this solves it for you also.

Answer (score 0):

Bro, I was working on this problem and eventually figure it out:

1- All you need to do is changing the path of the image from your JSON file. That means the path should be related to your react component (BlogCard).

2- Next thing, instead of using

```
<MyComponent
    image={release.imageURL}  // ==> WRONG
/>
```

Just go with:

```
<MyComponent
    image={`${release.imageURL}`} // ===> CORRECT
/>
```

Good Luck !!

Answer (score 0):

Simply react works by rendering jsx so At first always try to maintain javascript or variables before return or render so js works properly in react app . You can try this method and keep your images in public folder.
1.

```js
import { Col, Row, Container, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';
import img from '../path

export default function BlogCard() {

  return (
    <Image src={img} roundedCircle />
  );
});
```