# ReactJS - Local Image not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I have image paths in an array and I want to display the images when I map the array. My code is as follows :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ItemsList extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            products: [
               {
                "name": "Item 1",
                "imageURL": "../images/milk.jpg"
               },
               {
                "name": "Item 2",
                "imageURL": "../images/bread.jpg"
               },
            ]
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { products } = this.state;
        return (
        <div>
        
                <div className="row">
                    {
                        products.map((val, ind) => {

                            return (
                                <div className="card mx-2 my-2 shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" key={ind} style={{ width: '345px', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <img src={val.imageURL}  className="card-img-top" style={{ height: '240px', width: '240px' }} alt="product image" />   // *** Displaying Image Here ***
                                    <div className="card-body" style={{ backgroundColor: '#a6b0bf', width: '100%', textAlign: 'center' }}>
                                        <h5 className="card-title">{val.name}</h5>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </div>

        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ItemsList;
```

The image is not displaying. I want to display the image in the map method but can't get it done. Need help.

Comment: this is producing a syntax error on the dot

Comment: I think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63253484/how-to-get-image-url-from-local-json-file-in-react-js

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use require:

```
<img src={require(`${val.imageURL}`)}  className="card-img-top" />
```

Comment: I am getting the following error after applying your solution ----> Cannot find module '../images/milk.jpg'

Comment: try to change "../images/milk.jpg" I think the order of the folder "images".

Comment: try to import an image of them (import image from "../") to find if you write the correct Hierarchical of folders